# Implementing Custom Transitions With Custom Container Controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uikit-transitions

I am trying to create a custom container controller within my iPhone app.  I would like this container to implement custom transitions, just like the default behavior of TabBarControllers and NavigationControllers within iOS 7.  I have successfully been able to add custom animations to my transitions, but am having trouble adding the interactive logic.

As part of the transition process, I must create a TransitionContext.  This is normally created by the system, but since I am using a custom container controller I have created my own class that conforms to the UIViewControllerContextTransitioningProtocol.  When the gesture recognizer tied to the transition is triggered, I attempt to begin the transition by calling:

```
[self.horizontalSwipeInteractionController startInteractiveTransition:transitionContext];
```

where self.horizontalSwipeInteractionController inherits from UIPercentDriveInteractiveTranstion.  Unfortunately, I get the following error at this point:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PrivateTransitionContext _animator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14654a80
```

I don't understand what to do now.  The documentation gives no examples on how to implement custom transitions with custom container controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `UIPercentDriveInteractiveTranstion` uses private APIs.

Alek Åström writes about this on his [iOS Nomad blog](http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/5/12/interactive-custom-container-view-controller-transitions) where he walks through creating an interactive custom container controller (emphasis added):

> ... we can see that UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition looks for the animator in our context, calling an undocumented method. Conveniently enough, all Apple-made transition contexts implement this method and that's how the percent driven transition can fire the animation. Unfortunately, that means **we cannot use the class for our own custom container view controllers.**

He recommends using [`AWPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`](https://github.com/MrAlek/AWPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition) as a drop in replacement.